# How to convert between csv.reader and csv.DictReader objects?

Tags: python, csv

I have the need to deal using cvs.reader objects because of the order of the columnts must be preserved.
But, I would like also to have the csv.DictReader object for some other reasons.

Now, is there a simple posibility to convert them between each other without having re-reading the file?

Comment: AFAIK `DictWriter` *does* preserve the order in which columns are written, so I don't understand what you are asking. Can you provide an example code that you would like to use, its expected output and the output you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/) instead.

```
ds = tablib.Dataset()
ds.csv = open(csvfile).read()
```

Then you can iter over `ds` as a sequence of rows, and `ds.dict` gives you a list of `OrderedDict` instances for each row. It's much easier if you also need to get it to other formats, or edit and save again as csv.